# PHP - Reading Directory vs Fetching from Database

Tags: php, database, memory, directory, glob

my main reason is get an opinion over different options. I have files/thumbs in a directory which are associated with a video and when i have to get them i use glob() function glob(DIRECTORY./file_name*.jpg); and it returns an array of all JPG files of the video.

glob function itself is very fast but still i am concerned about usage because on each page there can be 20 to 50 videos so there will be 20 to 50 glob calls, should i keep using it or start putting data in database to fetch files list from there instead of glob(); ?

if there is a better alternative, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: considering there are 50+ users online at once.

Comment: The core problem in this question seems to be that you are "concerned about usage", but it's not clear all what you mean by that. Please explain the problem that concerns you more clearly so that we can help. In your opinion, what exactly is the problem with the way you are doing this now?

Comment: Thanks Nate. Yes my main concern is CPU/Memory or you can say performance. Which option is better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As usual with performance questions, results may vary quite a bit, so the answer is: what's faster is what works faster for **you**.

The place to start is to measure how much time it takes to do things as you are doing them now. Once you have done this, ask yourself: is this fast enough? It may be that, although it might not be the fastest way to do things, it's still so fast that speed is not a concern.

How much of the time processing a page is spent getting the file globs? 1%? 10%? 50%? The higher this percentage is, the more worthwhile it becomes to consider changing how you do things.

Also, how is site performance as a whole? If you doubled the speed of each page load, would people notice? If not, then it may not really be worth doing performance tuning yet even if you see the obvious place to do so.

If you think you could do better, implement the functionality using your database and measure if that is faster. Again, results with this could be highly variable. For example, if **your** database is under a heavy load, getting the results from the database might be much slower. If you have a massively powerful database that's barely used, it might be very fast. Only testing can tell you the truth.

I will add that the way you are doing things now seems simpler and more maintainable, because it finds filenames based on the actual files on your disk. If you try to use a database, you will have to worry about synchronizing the list of filenames in the database with the list of files in the filesystem.

One thing to be aware of, though, is that many filesystems perform worse when you have a single directory with a very large number of files in it. If you have this situation, consider splitting the files up into multiple subdirectories. A popular approach is to make directories with names a-z and then put all files beginning with "a" in the "a" directory, all files beginning with "b" in the "b" directory, etc. However, this will probably only be important once you have tens of thousands of files, and even then it depends on the particular filesystem and the hardware it runs on.

(Edit based on comments:)

Since you are talking about pre-computing the results and storing those in the database, I suggest that a better approach than putting things in a database is to use a caching server like http://memcached.org/. You can look at this as a hybrid approach: you still do things the way you are doing them now, but each time you want a result, you first check the cache to see if it contains the result; if it does, used the cached result, otherwise compute the new glob. This avoids the problem of keeping database and filesystem in sync, because old cache entries can expire and be replaced by new, correct ones.

Comment: Thanks I will now perform a test, it will be on a local environment so results may vary but still a good practice before I go live.

Comment: filename is unique and thumb files are like filename-1.jpg , filename-2.jpg, filename-3.jpg and so on, there can be 1 to 30 thumbs of each video. I was thinking of use database because once data is saved i dont have to glob each time. just re-use the data which is already saved and with the combination of json(ed) array things can be much faster...

Comment: I see what you mean. That is inherently faster because the result is pre-computed for you. Instead of a database, though, I suggest using a caching server like memcached, it is more appropriate for this use.

Comment: I am using dated folders.
/thumbs/2012/8/31/filename-1.jpg and so on...

I writing code to use json and database so i can store all file names in a single field. I can use memcache but i have to write a code which suites most of the server environment as my code is open-source (ClipBucket) and not many people are well-aware of caching and stuff so thats why i was worried about memory. Thanks again for your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already storing information for the video itself in the database, you might consider storing just the number of thumbs per video in the table that holds the video data. This would be much faster than having to query a separate table of full filenames because you'd only have to reference a field in a record that you've already queried. This might be a good compromise between your two current ideas. You'd have to make sure that the names of your thumbs are consistent and programmable, however. For example, given only that video 123 has 4 thumbs, you can generate:

```
/path/to/video_123/thumb_01.jpg
/path/to/video_123/thumb_02.jpg
/path/to/video_123/thumb_03.jpg
/path/to/video_123/thumb_04.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks for that but thumbs have different sizes as well and user can also upload custom thumbs and delete existing , filename is basically a prefix of the thumbs. thumbs can also have name like filename-300x240-2.jpg 

My old code was using increments only and i was storing the number but now its little more than just an increment. THanks for the suggestion, i am storing a json(ed) array now and I think it will serve the purpose. 

S.O has Awesome People and Great community.